# Write a program to ask the user to enter the amount spent on food and Gas for each day of the week

Tags: python

My assignment is to write a program to ask the user to enter the amount spent on food and Gas for each day of the week. Count and display the number of days the user spent more than 20 dollars per day on food and more than 10 dollars/per day on gas. The problem I have is that I don't know how to make the output say, "You spent more than 20 dollars per day on food in _ days of the week." And "You spent more than 10 dollars per day on gas in _ days of the week." Because the I have to input the answer between the quotes and either it says syntax error, or puts it on a new line. My code is:

```
over20food=0;
over10gas=0;
food=input("Please enter the amount spent on food on Monday:");
if (food>20):
    over20food = over20food + 1;
gas=input("Please enter the amount spent on gas on Monday:");
if (gas>10):
    over10gas = over10gas + 1;
food=input("Please enter the amount spent on food on Tuesday:");
if (food>20):
    over20food = over20food + 1;
gas=input("Please enter the amount spent on gas on Tuesday:");
if (gas>10):
    over10gas = over10gas + 1;
food=input("Please enter the amount spent on food on Wednesday:");
if (food>20):
    over20food = over20food + 1;
gas=input("Please enter the amount spent on gas on Wednesday:");
if (gas>10):
    over10gas = over10gas + 1;
food=input("Please enter the amount spent on food on Thursday:");
if (food>20):
    over20food = over20food + 1;
gas=input("Please enter the amount spent on gas on Thursday:");
if (gas>10):
    over10gas = over10gas + 1;
food=input("Please enter the amount spent on food on Friday:");
if (food>20):
    over20food = over20food + 1;
gas=input("Please enter the amount spent on gas on Friday:");
if (gas>10):
    over10gas = over10gas + 1;
food=input("Please enter the amount spent on food on Saturday:");
if (food>20):
    over20food = over20food + 1;
gas=input("Please enter the amount spent on gas on Saturday:");
if (gas>10):
    over10gas = over10gas + 1;
food=input("Please enter the amount spent on food on Sunday:");
if (food>20):
    over20food = over20food + 1;
gas=input("Please enter the amount spent on gas on Sunday:");
if (gas>10):
    over10gas = over10gas + 1;
print("You spent more than 20 dollars per day on food in" +str(over20food) "days of the week");
print("You spent more than 10 dollars per day on gas in" +str (over10gas));
```

Comment: Have you guys learned `lists` yet? You could simplify this

Comment: You don't need semicolons at the end of lines in Python.

Comment: @vash_the_stampede No we have not learned lists

Comment: @wwii Yes, I know that now. I just forget, because I learned C# first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a '+' in your first print statement.

Should be

```
print("You spent more than 20 dollars per day on food in" +str(over20food) + "days of the week")
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how to make a space after the word "in"? It isn't important but the website I turn it in marks my assignment as wrong, because I don't have a space after the word "in."

Comment: See Bazingaa's comments on his answer below

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt was almost correct. You were just missing a `+` in the first line. My answer below assumes that your rest of the code is working fine and variables `over20food` and `over10gas` are correct.

Also, as John Gordon pointed out, you should put `int()` around **ALL** of your `input()` commands as `int(input())`

```
print("You spent more than 20 dollars per day on food in" + str(over20food) + "days of the week");
print("You spent more than 10 dollars per day on gas in" + str(over10gas) + "days of the week");
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how to make a space after the word "in"? It isn't important but the website I turn it in marks my assignment as wrong, because I don't have a space after the word "in."

Comment: Just put a space in the string as `"You spent more than 10 dollars per day on gas in  "`

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns strings.  If you want to read input as numeric values, you'll need to call `int()` on the result, like so:

```
gas = int(input("Please enter the amount spent on gas on Sunday:"))
```

Your `print()` was wrong because you didn't have a `+` after the variable name, between it and the remainder of the message.

Also, get rid of those semicolons.  Python doesn't need them.